# I have a lot of big ui-selects on one page and would like to add options on focus

Tags: angularjs, ui-select, angular-ui-select

My page has 50 orders, where each line contains the following `ui-select`. `$scope.largeListOfBooks` contains about 360 items.

So `$scope.largeListOfBooks` is loaded once on document load and should only be loaded to the `ui-select` that has been focused.

Is it possible to load the options (`repeat`) only when the user focuses the select-box?

```
<ui-select ng-model="myOrder.someBook" class="ui-select-input-xs">
  <ui-select-match placeholder="Select a book">
    {{ $select.selected.shortDescription }} ({{ $select.selected.theIsbn }})
  </ui-select-match>
  <ui-select-choices repeat="book.title as book in largeListOfBooks | customSearchFilter:$select.search">
    <div>
      <span ng-bind-html="book.shortDescription | highlight: $select.search"></span>
    </div>
    <small ng-bind-html="book.theIsbn | highlight: $select.search"></small>
  </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

Comment: Verify this might help you http://fiddle.jshell.net/TigerC10/g862L/

Comment: @user3249448 Thanks for that. Unfortunately my test results differ from the results listed. Probably different versions.The solution to load the items via AJAX wouldn't work for me, as all lists are basically the same and would thus (as you described) be a lot of useless overhead. FYI: the `largeListOfBooks` needs to be loaded just once and should then be loaded from the variable every time, not the server.